# Problemas de estilo con carrusel

Tags: html, css, vue.js

Estoy realizando un carrusel en Vue JS con CSS y JS con el siguiente código dentro del archivo .vue

```js
<script>
export default {
  data(){
    return {
      slides: [
        {
          imagen: 'bannerA',
          id: 1
        },
        {
          imagen: 'bannerB',
          id: 2
        },{
          imagen: 'bannerC',
          id: 3
        }
      ]
    }
  },

  methods: {
    next () {
      const first = this.slides.shift()
      this.slides = this.slides.concat(first)
    },
    previous () {
      const last = this.slides.pop()
      this.slides = [last].concat(this.slides)
    }
  },

  created() {
    setInterval(this.next, 3500);
  }
};
</script>
```

```css
<style scoped>
.banner-inicio {
  background-image: url("../../imagenes/estructura.jpg");
  background-position: top;
  /* Cubir el área del div */
  background-size: cover;
  /* Acomodar la posición al fondo y relativa a la pantalla */
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
  /* Arreglar que se acomode al 100% de la altura de la pantalla */
  width: 100%;
  height: 670px;
}

.banner-inicio .texto-banner {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  font-size: 46px;
  position: absolute;
}
 /* Carrusel */

 .carousel-view {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.carousel {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 400px;
}
.slide {
  flex: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.slide:first-of-type {
  opacity: 0;
}
.slide:last-of-type {
  opacity: 0;
}

.bannerA{
  background-image: url("../../imagenes/estructura.jpg");
  background-position: top;
  /* Cubir el área del div */
  background-size: cover;
  /* Acomodar la posición al fondo y relativa a la pantalla */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  /* Arreglar que se acomode al 100% de la altura de la pantalla */
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
.bannerB{
  
  background-image: url("../../imagenes/banner-servicios.jpg");
  background-position: top;
  /* Cubir el área del div */
  background-size: cover;
  /* Acomodar la posición al fondo y relativa a la pantalla */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -2;
  /* Arreglar que se acomode al 100% de la altura de la pantalla */
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
.bannerC{
  
  background-image: url("../../imagenes/banner-quienessomos.jpg");
  background-position: top;
  /* Cubir el área del div */
  background-size: cover;
  /* Acomodar la posición al fondo y relativa a la pantalla */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -3;
  /* Arreglar que se acomode al 100% de la altura de la pantalla */
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
</style>
```

```html
<template>
  <div class="contenedor">
    <!--<div class="banner-inicio">
      <div class="texto-banner">
        <h4>Mantenimiento Industrial Heros</h4>
        <p>
          Empresa de mantenimientos industriales, fabricacion de productos metalicos, servicio de torno,
          y montaje de estructuras metalicas.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>-->
    <div class="carousel-view">
      <transition-group
        class="carousel"
        tag="div">
        <div
          v-for="slide in slides"
          class='slide'
          :key="slide.id">
          <div :class="slide.imagen"></div>
        </div>
      </transition-group>
      <div class="carousel-controls">
        <button class='carousel-controls__button' @click="previous">Anterior</button>
        <button class='carousel-controls__button' @click="next">Siguiete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h1>TITULO PRINCIPAL DE LA APLICACIÓN BLA BLA BLA BLA</h1>
  </div>
</template>
```

Pero como encima de éste hay otro componente que sería la barra de navegación y debajo el pié de página del sitio.. mi problema se encuentra en que el carrusel se empieza a mostrar justo debajo de la barra de navegación.

La finalidad que busco es que el carrusel también se encuentre debajo de la barra de navegación.. pero que el footer no se sobreponga sobre el carrusel también.

[image: Precisamente quiero que el carrusel se vea debajo de la barra de navegación pero evitar que también se sobre ponga el pié de página como suede en la imagen]

Comment: Hola Andres, lee sobre cómo crear un [mcve] y edita la pregunta para que podamos ver el problema directamente en la publicación. Y completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio (y con ello ganarás una nueva medalla).

Comment: El ejemplo proporcionado no está funcionando correctamente.